# Cursor Index Out Of Bounds Exception in android

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

There is a score Board in My game..There is no score still it shows CursoreIndexOutOfBoundsException how am i suppose to solve this error..there are many solution but it didnt work for me below is my code

```
public List<Rank> getRanking() {
    List<Rank> listRanking = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Rank Order By Score DESC LIMIT 10;", null);
    try {

        if (c == null)
        {return null;}

        c.moveToNext();
        do {
            int Id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));
            int Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Score"));


            Rank ranking = new Rank(Id, Score);
            listRanking.add(ranking);
        } while (c.moveToNext());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return listRanking;

}
```

Can anyone help me with a solution to this problem.Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this it will work:-

```
public List<Rank> getRanking() {
    List<Rank> listRanking = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Rank Order By Score DESC LIMIT 10;", null);
    try {

        if (c == null)
        {return null;}

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            int index = c.getColumnIndex("ID");
            int Id = 0;
            if (-1 != index) {
                Id = c.getInt(index);
            }
            index = c.getColumnIndex("Score");
            int Score = 0;
            if (-1 != index) {
                Score = c.getInt(index1);
            }


            Rank ranking = new Rank(Id, Score);
            listRanking.add(ranking);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (null != c) {
            c.close();
        }
        db.close();
    }
    return listRanking;

}
```

Comment: DId'nt work by doing this the app forcefully stopped

Comment: are you sure you'r using the same code which creates ANR.

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
        textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Scores");

        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstRanking);
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        List<Rank> lstRanking = db.getRanking();

        if (lstRanking.size() > 0) {
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, lstRanking);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


    }

Comment: And it is recommended to perform Database operation in the background thread because it block the main thread which creates ANR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138817/discussion-between-ankit-gusain-and-avi).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first c.moveToNext() to c.moveToFirst():

```
public List<Rank> getRanking() {
    List<Rank> listRanking = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Rank Order By Score DESC LIMIT 10;", null);
    try {

        if (c == null)
        {return null;}
//changed moveToNext() to moveToFirst()
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                int Id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                int Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Score"));


                Rank ranking = new Rank(Id, Score);
                listRanking.add(ranking);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return listRanking;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are moving to next, when there is no next. You need to check and make sure there is a next to go to. Also, get rid of the first `c.moveToNext()`. You don't need it. It makes you skip over the first value. Just do:

```
       try {

        if (c == null){
             return null;
        }
        do {
            int Id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));
            int Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Score"));


            Rank ranking = new Rank(Id, Score);
            listRanking.add(ranking);
            if(c.moveToNext() == null){
                 break;
             }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: @AnkitGusain where are you getting the error? What line?

Comment: in android monitor after do statement

Comment: I would check the numeric value of `c.getColumnIndex("ID");`, and check that number against the count of the cursor. It appears that call is out of bounds of the cursor. I'm guessing that you are getting -1, which is why you get the OOB error.